# XSLT Transformation for ABAP to XML

Tags: xslt, abap

I am writing XSLT Transformation for converting ABAP data to XML and to your kind knowledge I don't know XML or XSLT either but still trying.

## PROBLEM:

I don't know how to write transformation code for below XML string:

> ```
> <INVOICE-PARTICULARS SL-NO="1">
> <INVOICE-PARTICULARS>
> ```

Here "INVOICE-PARTICULARS" is an element, "SL-NO" is a node of "INVOICE-PARTICULARS", and "1" is a value of database field DLINVSR.

I have tried with below mentioned code but failed in getting result I want.

## MY-PRESENT CODE:

> ```
> <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;INVOICE-PARTICULARS&gt;</xsl:text>
> <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;SL-NO&gt;</xsl:text>
> <xsl:value-of select="DLINVSR"/>
> <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/SL-NO&gt;</xsl:text>
> <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/INVOICE-PARTICULARS&gt;</xsl:text>
> ```

Comment: You can use xslt to convert from xml to xml and from xml to other formats. It can't be used to convert something that isn't xml to xml.

Comment: Dear Robert, Thanks for your reply. If a XSLT Transformation is in place, we can use it through ABAP code to covert ABAP data to XML. For your kind information I have created XML through very process but not in desired format. Please answer to my question if you have any clue. Thanks & Warm Regards.

Comment: @Yogesh Pathak: Please, provide input sample.

Comment: This is not a real question. You have not provided any source XML document that needs to be transformed, you have not provided the required output from the transformation of the source XML document, you have not provided any requirements to the transformation and any mappings from items of the source XML document to items of the output. I have voted to `C L O S E` this question.

Comment: ...plus shouting probably won't help your case...

Comment: Sorry I could not turned up to my office as I was sick, meanwhile Mr.Dimitre Novatchev has voted to close this question, sorry Mr.vwegert also that I could not replied on time. Now I am ready with my schema and xml file and transformation also for your reference, can I provide you the same so that you can comment on that. Once again sorry for not replying on time. Warm Regards,

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:template match="INVOICE-PARTICULARS">`

```
       <xsl:value-of select="@SL-NO" />
```

`</xsl:template>`

You prefix @ to the name of the attribute.

Comment: Dear Raj,  Thanks for your answer. Can I mail you the whole Transformation Code, here I can't copy complete code. Looking at the complete code you can understand what I exactly want. Please

Answer (score 0):

XSLT can only process XML data into something else, not the other way around. Therefore, before applying a transformation, you need to actually get XML from the ABAP data.

The second part of this article covers this: http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/content/view/15/1/

Comment: I AM DOING AN ALV REPORT PROGRAM WHICH ALSO HAS A FACILITY TO CONVERT ABAP DATA TO XML.  A sample XML file is given by Excise Dept. of India and a XSD (schema) file also given, just I have to write XSLT Transformation to convert ABAP data to XML. The XML created with the help of program must match with the sample XML file given. And created XML will be validated by given XSD (Schema) file.

Comment: No need to yell (ALL UPPERCASE). The point is that ABAP is not XML, and cannot directly be processed by XSLT. Period. You first need to obtain XML before you can start the XSL transformation process.